# What is the appropriate phrase for whispering to someone's ear?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

[image]

What is the appropriate phrase/word for whispering into someone's (most probably a close friend) ear generally to share some secret about someone else?

Comment: It's 'whispering in someone's ear'.

Comment: I don't think we have a single word for this. Sharing secrets about someone is gossiping, but it doesn't have to be whispered (unless the person being discussed could hear it).